# (C++) Overloading operator << , overwrite the output if I do not use endl

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I am doing a C++ project for the university. I have to make a chronology of historical events. I have a class to save the events, called "FechaHistorica", with a `set<string>` and `int` as private members. The set contains strings, each string is one historical event. The int is the year when all that events happened.
The other class is called "Cronologia", with a `map<int,FechaHistorica>` to store every "FechaHistorica".

The problem is with the operator << of FechaHistorica I guess. The executbale recives two .txt files with movies, and the outpout should be the union of both documents. Here is the code for the operator << os FechaHistorica:

```
const char SEP = '#';
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const FechaHistorica& e) {
    os << e.getYear();

    for(const_iterator p = e.eventos.begin(); p != e.eventos.end(); ++p)
        os << SEP << *p;

    return os;
}
```

The output is:

```
victor@victor-GL552VW:~/Documentos/Universidad/1º Cuatrimestre/Estructura de dat
os/Practicas/Practicas-ED/Práctica 4 - STL e Iteradores$ ./bin/prueba movies.txt
 films.txt
Cronología leida del archivo: 
0
1900#Sherlock Holmes Baffled#The Enchanted Drawing
1901#Scrooge, or, Marley's Ghost#Star Theatre
1902#A Trip to the Moon
#The Great Train Robbery Fireman
1904#The Impossible Voyage
1905#Adventures of Sherlock Holmes; or, Held for Ransom
#Humorous Phases of Funny Faces#The Story of the Kelly Gang
1907#Ben Hur#L'Enfant prodigue
#Fantasmagorie#The Assassination of the Duke of Guise#The Taming of the Shrew#The Thieving Hand
#The Country Doctoreat#Les Misérables#Princess Nicotine; or, The Smoke Fairy
1910#In Old California'
1911#Defence of Sevastopol#L'Inferno
1912#Independenţa României#The Musketeers of Pig Alley
1913#Barney Oldfield's Race for a Life#Fantômas#Raja Harishchandra#The Bangville Police
1914#Judith of Bethulia#The Perils of Pauline#Tillie's Punctured Romance
1915#A Fool There Was#Birth of a Nation#Les Vampires#The Tramp
```

As you can see, some years are not printed correct, the output should be:

```
1900#Sherlock Holmes Baffled#The Enchanted Drawing
1901#Scrooge, or, Marley's Ghost#Star Theatre
1902#A Trip to the Moon
1903#The Great Train Robbery#Life of an American Fireman
1904#The Impossible Voyage
1905#Adventures of Sherlock Holmes; or, Held for Ransom
1906#The Story of the Kelly Gang#Humorous Phases of Funny Faces#Dream of a Rarebit Fiend
1907#Ben Hur#L'Enfant prodigue
1908#Fantasmagorie#The Taming of the Shrew#The Thieving Hand#The Assassination of the Duke of Guise#A Visit to the Seaside
1909#The Country Doctor#A Corner in Wheat#Les Misérables#Princess Nicotine; or, The Smoke Fairy
1910#In Old California'
1911#L'Inferno#Defence of Sevastopol
1912#Independenţa României#The Musketeers of Pig Alley
1913#The Bangville Police#Barney Oldfield's Race for a Life#Fantômas#Raja Harishchandra
1914#The Perils of Pauline#Judith of Bethulia#Tillie's Punctured Romance
1915#Birth of a Nation#Les Vampires#The Tramp#A Fool There Was
```

Well, if I add `endl` after every event, the output is correct, I mean,  `os << SEP << *p << endl;` instead of  `os << SEP << *p;`, but I don't want to have endl after each historical event in the output. What can I do?

I hope you can help me, thanks.

The files with data are "movies.txt" and "films.txt"
The full code of the proyect is here: https://github.com/vicase/Practicas-ED/tree/master/Pr%C3%A1ctica%204%20-%20STL%20e%20Iteradores

Comment: Have a look at [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl). The `std::endl` does actually two things: output of `'\n'` and `flush`. If you don't want the `'\n'` but the `flush` then simply add `<< `[`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) at end of output.

Comment: I tried with      os << SEP << *p << flush; but it doesn't work. If i make cout << endl; in the operator << before      os << SEP << *p << flush; it works, but I have the endl again. I do not understand why it does not work

Comment: Make small input files. Debug step by step. Break down individual parts of your software and test them isolated. Find out what's going wrong. I had a short look into your source code: `main()` has no `return`. Don't use `while (!feof())` ([Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/7478597)). In general, this is far too much code to ask for help on this site. Concerning your output operator: output should work with `std::endl` as well as with `std::flush` as well as without both of them. Hence, there might be broken something else.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: the problem was that the first txt was in crlf format (Windows) and the other one was in LF(Ubuntu). With both documents in LF works ok. Thanks everybody